# How to fetch all headers of several messages in MailKit

Tags: c#, mailkit

**In MailKit,**

You can fetch the IMessageSummary (containing the **specified headers** and the full message) for several messages with the following

```cs
ImapFolder folder;
List<UniqueId> uids;
var messageSummaries = folder.Fetch(uids, 
                                    MessageSummaryItems.Full, 
                                    new HashSet<string>{"X-Mailer"});
```

If a pass an empty `HashSet<string>`, I get a `System.ArgumentException: The set of header fields cannot be empty`.

How can I fetch **all headers available** ?

*Note: I know that I could get the headers on each message, one by one, but it is too slow to match my performance needs.*

Answer (score 3):

## Hacking into MailKit

As MailKit is open-source, I just modified the code of `ImapFolderFetch` to handle the fetch for all headers and made a pull request. The owner of the library improved it by adding a new value in `MessageSummaryItems`.

**Usage:**

```
var messageSummaries = folder.Fetch(uids, MessageSummaryItems.Headers);
```

*Note: Until a new release is done, you ll have to build your own from [github master](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit).*